# Change the visualization value on input field in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a state which has a field value as number which contains many decimals. I want to parse it to fixed(2).

But if I do so in the value of my input I have problems when typing a new value, and only accepts the first number. I can type 4 and gets 4.00 but I can't type 44 neither add decimals.

Is there a way to isolate the value which is displayed from the actual value?

I don't want to parse the value before because I would lost precision and my real value would change. The idea is just trimming my value which is displayed in the input only for visualization purpose.

```
 <input
       onChange={e=>setTakeUp(e.target.value)}
       value={(+takeup).toFixed(2)} />
```

Comment: you are passing object as a value, try: value={parseTakeupLine(takeUp).value}}

Comment: That was my bad trying to make the example simpler while writing the question I missed this. I just corrected my question to make it even simpler.

Comment: Why not just use onBlur instead? Or you could try component library like antd https://ant.design/components/input-number/ and try to play with parser or formatter props or use just precision property

Comment: using onBlur could be a good aproach I think!  thanks